# Two Strings, split and pair using loop c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dynamics-crm

Basically, I'm trying to query the CRM Sql DB Audit Table. I have two columns, one contains the data that has been changed, one contains the mapping for those changes.

Changes are split using ~, mapping is split using ,.

So effectively I have...

Animal, Vehicle, building

Dog~Car~House

I need to loop through pairing them in order, until I get to a particular pairing.

For Instance, if the pairing food and burger exists, then do something.

Animal, Vehicle, building, food

Dog~Car~House~Burger

Is this achievable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
var keys = String.Split(",");
var vals = String.Split("~");

var findKey = "food";
var findVal = "pie";

for(var i = 0;i < keys.length; i++)
{
  if (keys[i] == findKey  && vals[i] == findVal)
  {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accessing Audit data directly in the SQL DB, you might want to consider getting it via the API, which will continue to work if you migrate to D365 Online.

As [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/sample-audit-entity-data-changes) shows, you can use the `RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest` and/or the `RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest` to get the Audit data in a usable format.